# App launch on startup in codename one

Tags: codenameone

How to launch the app(android) when the device startup?

I want my app has to run in background even the app is not open.To overcome the issue,i want to launch it on device startup,but i cannot find any solution.Please help me to resolve the issue in codenameone.

Answer (score 0):

While launching on startup is doable in Android it is not doable in any other OS. Background execution is also severely limited outside of Android and is now facing restrictions in Android too thanks to project doze.

In that light you can use native interfaces to do this on Android. We support background use cases that work on iOS/Android as explained in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).